# how to disable a layout and its contents programatically in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 4 LinearLayouts in a RelativeLayout and I am also using an ImageView. When the ImageView is displayed I want to disable the 4 LinearLayouts and their contents. Each LinearLayout contains 4 buttons. Shown below is my function to disable and enable these layouts. Can someone help me understand why this isn't working?

```
private void disablelayout(final LinearLayout l1,final LinearLayout l2,final LinearLayout l3,final LinearLayout l4)
    {
        l1.setEnabled(false);
        l2.setEnabled(false);
        l3.setEnabled(false);
        l4.setEnabled(false);

    }
    private void enablelayout(final LinearLayout l1,final LinearLayout l2,final LinearLayout l3,final LinearLayout l4)
    {
        l1.postDelayed(new Runnable(){             
             @Override             
             public void run() {                 
                 l1.setEnabled(true); 
                 l2.setEnabled(true); 
                 l3.setEnabled(true); 
                 l4.setEnabled(true); 
             }         
             }, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to make it invisible.layouts should be visible.but user should not be able to click on buttons in th layouts

Answer (score 4):

```
private void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);

    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

        for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
            enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setVisibility() to either INVISIBLE or GONE.

Comment: if i set this the linearlayouts will be invisible.rt?but i dnt want to make it invisible

Comment: I thought by disabled you meant not able to be seen. Perhaps you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205384/android-mass-enable-disable-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "`Clickable`" property for all items to false. The method is `setClickable(boolean).`
After that no one could click it. Also you could look into this question: [How to disable an Android button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button)

Comment: i tried this...but still i can click on buttons...i had set this property for layouts..that s y i asked u...is it necessary to set dis to all the cntrls in d layouts..it s really difficult..

Comment: Each View has "Duplicate parent state" property (in visual editor too). Set it to true for all buttons and other Vies you want. After thet use setEnabled(false); to layout. It should work.

Comment: i had set the Duplicate parent state property for all buttons.but still same problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
Use can use this for hide the whole layout

l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

whenever you want to display particular layout then you can 

l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```