# How to disable all buttons in Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I create an app which need to disable all buttons to allow user to leave the application - back button, menu button, camera button, call button, etc, and app should have 1 button for exit. I don't know how to disable all buttons. Tell me please, thank you

Comment: You can't and shouldn't. You can specify your activity wants all button-related events and consume them, but it doesn't work for all buttons.

Comment: And do you think the OS should allow an application like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Physical buttons? No, you can't disable all of them. Home button needs to work... [Android - Is It possible to disable the click of home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button)

Related: [Android: mass enable/disable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205384/android-mass-enable-disable-buttons)

Comment: Thank you. But how can I disable "stop-calling" button also?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: when you enter the activity, call

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
```

and when you exit the activity, call

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION);
```