# Android: mass enable buttons which are already disabled

Tags: android, button, android-tablelayout

I have tried using the code mentioned in the link below to "mass disable" buttons and it works perfectly fine. However the same code does not work for mass enable.

[Android: mass enable/disable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205384/android-mass-enable-disable-buttons)

**Code for Disable (Working)**

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1); // 
ArrayList<View> touchables = tl.getTouchables();
for(View touchable : touchables){
if( touchable instanceof Button && touchable != btnNewWord )
((Button)touchable).setEnabled(false);
}
```

**CODE for Enable (Not Working)**

```
btnNewWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);  
ArrayList<View> touchables = tl.getTouchables();
for(View touchable : touchables){
if( touchable != btnNewWord )
((Button)touchable).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error or so? try to Log your ArrayList to check if it contains values once you disable the buttons and try to get ArrayList again??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you set the buttons disabled,i think,they will no longer be touchable. So you need to modify that point in your code and use something else to get all views. You can preserve your `ArrayList` which you used to disable buttons and then use the same to re enable them.

**EDIT :**

Try this:

```
ArrayList<View> touchables //declare globaly
```

then

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1); // 
touchables = tl.getTouchables();
for(View touchable : touchables)
{
    if( touchable instanceof Button && touchable != btnNewWord )
      ((Button)touchable).setEnabled(false);
}
```

and now,

```
btnNewWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

       for(View touchable : touchables)
       {
          if( touchable != btnNewWord )
            ((Button)touchable).setEnabled(true);
       }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I disable all except one button which is still enabled ie btnNewWord: 

    if( touchable instanceof Button && touchable != btnNewWord ) 

I want the user to click that particular button to re-enable all buttons again.

Comment: That means,you have btnNewWord is the button which controls the disability of all other buttons.right? then you need to save all buttons(when they are enabled) in ArrayList<View> as you did,and then you have to use the same ArrayList<View> to re enable button in onClick() of btnNewWord.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and effort to put the explanation across to me. Though the code still isn't working I can now understand the problem and am trying to get a workaround.

Comment: Thanks to all ...it worked after i followed the inputs from Hiral